# расстановка элементов навигации

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Пытаюсь сделать навигацию по сайту. У всего сайта, кроме футера есть отступы слева и справа по 230px.
Мне нужно, чтобы последний элемент навигации был выровнен по правому краю и не заходил за границы, но когда я пытаюсь сдвинуть его вправо на максимум, то есть делаю margin 100% слева, он выравнивается не так, как надо и весь элемент находится за нужной границей
[image: 1]

на фото, чёрной линией показана нужная граница, и как вы можете видеть, текст выравнивается по справа от неё, а мне нужно, чтобы текст был слева от линии

```css
body {
 margin-left: 230px; /* отступы */
 margin-right: 230px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

#q1 { /* header */
 color: #454545;
 font-family: 'Pacifico', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 200;
 font-size: 40px;
}

.nav {
 list-style-type: none; /* Убираем маркеры у элементов списка */
 font-family: 'Bebas Neue', serif;
}

.m a {  /* the main-основной nav */
 font-size: 25px;
 color: #454545;
 position: absolute;
 top: 45px;
 text-decoration: none; /* убираем подчёркивание у ссылки */
}

.add { /* additional-дополнительное, span к nav */
 font-size: 15px;
 color: #BFBFBF;
 position: absolute;
 top: 30px;
}

.nav1 {
 margin-left: 40%; /*351*/
}


.nav2 {
 margin-left: 52.5%;
}

.nav3 {
 margin-left: 65%;
}

.nav4 {
 margin-left: 80%;
}

.nav5 {
 margin-left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>About</title>
  <link href="about.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img_Blitz/mini3.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bebas+Neue|Pacifico&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="C:\Users\Екатерина\Desktop/Blitz\img_Blitz\mini3.ico" type="image/x-icon">
 </head>
 <body>
  <header id="q1">Blitz</header>
  <nav>
   <div class="nav1">
   <span class="nav add">HOMEPAGE</span>
   <li class="nav m"><a href="C:\Users\Екатерина\Desktop\Blitz\home.html">HOME</a></li>
   </div>
   <div class="nav2">
   <span class="nav add">WHO WE ARE?</span>
   <li class="nav m"><a href="C:\Users\Екатерина\Desktop\Blitz\about\about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
   </div>
   <div class="nav3">
   <span class="nav add">MY PORTFOLIO</span>
   <li class="nav m"><a href="#">PROJECTS</a></li>
   </div>
   <div class="nav4">
   <span class="nav add">LATEST NEWS</span>
   <li class="nav m"><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
   </div>
   <div class="nav5">
   <span class="nav add">GET IN TOUCH</span>
   <li class="nav m"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
   </div>
  </nav>
 </body>
</html>
```

Upd: в окне для кода не достаточно место, поэтому там всё слиплось

Answer (score 0):

Вообще расставлять элементы навигации таким образом весьма оригинально :) Попробуй использовать `flexbox` как вариант. И еще... если заюзал `li`, то элементы списка надо вписывать в `ul` или `ol` так будет правильно.

Answer (score 0):

Наверно если писать капсом это зашкварно но всё же, я чуть чуть исправил html а из css взял только font-family

*В css есть такое правило `text-transform: uppercase` вот если надо текст написать большими буквами то есть в верхнем регистре применяйте его*

> добавил один медиа запрос в котором при до 520px он сработает и уберёт `.add` что бы это увидеть откройте `сниппет` на весь экран а сам `браузер` сожмите

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.top,
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  align-items: center;
}

header {
  font-family: 'Pacifico', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

[class*="nav"] {
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue', serif;
}

@media(max-width:520px) {
  .add {
    display: none;
  }
  header {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bebas+Neue|Pacifico&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<div class="top">

  <header id="q1">Blitz</header>
  <span class="trigger">
      <i></i>
      <i></i>
      <i></i>
    </span>
  <nav>
    <div class="nav1">
      <span class="nav add">HOMEPAGE</span>
      <li class="nav m"><a href="C:\Users\Екатерина\Desktop\Blitz\home.html">HOME</a></li>
    </div>
    <div class="nav2">
      <span class="nav add">WHO WE ARE?</span>
      <li class="nav m"><a href="C:\Users\Екатерина\Desktop\Blitz\about\about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
    </div>
    <div class="nav3">
      <span class="nav add">MY PORTFOLIO</span>
      <li class="nav m"><a href="#">PROJECTS</a></li>
    </div>
    <div class="nav4">
      <span class="nav add">LATEST NEWS</span>
      <li class="nav m"><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="nav5">
    <span class="nav add">GET IN TOUCH</span>
    <li class="nav m"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- li-элементы нужно заворачивать в ul
- лучше не пользоваться так активно абсолютным позиционированием
- можно использовать свойство CSS columns

https://codepen.io/DoubleS/pen/bGdMEQQ

```css
body {
  min-width: 480px;
  margin: 0 230px;
}

#q1 {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  min-width: 80px;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: "Pacifico", sans-serif;
  /* header */
  color: #454545;
}

.nav {
  list-style-type: none; 
  font-family: "Bebas Neue", serif;
  columns: 5;
  min-height: 70px;
}

.m {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height:70px;
}

.m a {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #454545;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.add {
  display: block;

  font-size: 15px;
  color: #bfbfbf;
}
 .m div {
  margin:  9px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .m {
    min-width: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>About</title>
    <link href="about.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img_Blitz/mini3.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bebas+Neue|Pacifico&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      rel="shortcut icon"
      href="C:\Users\Екатерина\Desktop/Blitz\img_Blitz\mini3.ico"
      type="image/x-icon"
    />
   
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div id="q1">Blitz</div>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="m">
          <div>
            <span class="add">HOMEPAGE</span>
            <a href="C:\Users\Екатерина\Desktop\Blitz\home.html">HOME</a>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li class="m">
          <div>
            <span class="add">WHO WE ARE?</span>
            <a href="C:\Users\Екатерина\Desktop\Blitz\about\about.html"
              >ABOUT</a
            >
          </div>
        </li>

        <li class="m">
          <div>
            <span class="add">MY PORTFOLIO</span>
            <a href="#">PROJECTS</a>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li class="m">
          <div>
            <span class="add">LATEST NEWS</span>
            <a href="#">BLOG</a>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li class="m">
          <div>
            <span class="add">GET IN TOUCH</span>
            <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
          </div>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </nav>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```