# отступы в навигации

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

хотелось бы расположить элементы nav'a на одинаковом расстоянии друг от друга
вот, как должно быть: 
[image: 1]

вот, что у меня:
[image: 2]

```css
a {
 text-decoration: none; /* убираем подчёркивание у ссылки */
}

li {
 list-style-type: none; /* Убираем маркеры */
}
.container {
 margin: 0 230px;
}

header .q1 {  
 float: left;
 color: #454545;
 font-family: 'Pacifico', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 200;
 font-size: 40px;
}

header ul {
 float: right;
 font-family: 'Bebas Neue', serif;
}

header ul li {
 float: left;
}

header a {
 font-size: 25px;
 color: #454545;
}
header ul li div {
 font-size: 15px;
 color: #BFBFBF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>About</title>
  <link href="about.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img_Blitz/mini3.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bebas+Neue|Pacifico&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="C:\Users\Екатерина\Desktop/Blitz\img_Blitz\mini3.ico" type="image/x-icon">
 </head>
 <body>
  <header class="container">
   <div class="q1">Blitz</div>
   <ul>
    <li>
     <div>Homepage</div>
     <a href="C:\Users\Екатерина\Desktop\Blitz\home.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <div>Who we are?</div>
     <a href="C:\Users\Екатерина\Desktop\Blitz\about\about.html">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <div>My portfolio</div>
     <a href="#">Projects</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <div>Latest news</div>
     <a href="#">Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <div>Get in touch</div>
     <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </header>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <footer></footer>
 </body>
</html>
```

Upd :Здесь как-то криво исполняется код, у меня в браузере всё отображается, как на 2 картинке
Upd2: линии, которые есть на картинках не нужно делать, это я криво обрезал

Comment: Добавьте в `header ul li` к примеру `padding-left: 40px;`

Comment: спасибо, работает

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [расстановка элементов навигации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1094729/%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Comment: Если что, я полностью изменил html, поэтому ответы на тот вопрос не очень-то подходят